# How do I change the value of a variable in a different file?

Tags: swift, string, uitextview

I am trying to read and write a variable to display in a note, and I can read it and it will display, but when I try and save what the user typed to that variable in the different file it will not save. 
Here is the variables I am trying to read and write in the Project file.

```
class Project
{
    var title = ""
    var content = ""
    var after = " "
}
```

And here is where I am trying to do the reading and writing.

```
class NoteDetailViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var contentTextField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var afterTextField: UITextView!

    var project = Project()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        titleTextField.text = project.title
        contentTextField.text = project.content
        afterTextField.text = project.after
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        project.title = titleTextField.text!
        project.content = contentTextField.text!
        project.after = afterTextField.text!
    }

}
```

I know the text field outlets aren't the problem because they show whatever value is originally in the variables, I simply can't save a new value to those variables from here.

Comment: Are you attempting to persist what the user typed to disk? You might want to check out `NSKeyedArchiver`/`NSKeyedUnarchiver`/`NSCoding` and/or `NSUserDefaults`. Are you getting an error with your code? What is it? As your code stands you aren't _saving_ anything to the disk, you are just creating an instance of `Project` in-memory and setting attributes on it. `project` will be deallocated as soon as your view controller is unloaded. If you want to use `project` elsewhere you need to grab a reference to it in another view controller or class.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, the value is just not translating back to the variable in the Project file. I thought the `project.title = titleTextField` and so on saves what is in the text fields to those variables in the project file, how do I do that? I don't want to use project any where else I just to save those values to Project.

Answer (score 0):

try this for dynamic global variable

```
class Project {
    static let sharedInstance = Project()

    var title = ""
    var content = ""
    var after = " "
}
```

But I need to save and retrieve data as below

```
// save title
Project.sharedInstance.title = "My Title"

// call / print title
print(Project.sharedInstance.title)
```

also take note this global variable is accessible from any classes

Comment: A little confused, what does putting that line in the project file do? Should that not go in the other file where I am saving?

Comment: it is a singleton object which is instantiated exactly once. so only one copy of the object available. the singleton object can be shared and reachable by any other object